# After domain or page how to add "/uk" slug? in wordpress custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

> [www.example.com/uk](http://www.example.com/uk)

> [www.example.com/page-name1/uk](http://www.example.com/page-name1/uk)

> [www.example.com/page-name2/uk](http://www.example.com/page-name2/uk)

```
> <?php class LanguageSwitcherPlugin {
>     public function __construct() {
>         add_action('init', array($this, 'add_language_rewrite_rule'));
>         add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'add_language_query_var'));
>     }
>     public function add_language_rewrite_rule() {
>         add_rewrite_rule(
>             '^uk/([^/]*)/?',
>             'index.php?uk=$matches[1]',
>             'top'
>         );
>     }
>     public function add_language_query_var($vars) {
>         $vars[] = 'uk';
>         return $vars;
>     } } $language_switcher = new LanguageSwitcherPlugin(); ?>
```

Comment: This code not worked, can you help me?

Comment: The pattern `^uk/([^/]*)/?` would match on URL paths that _start with_ `uk/`.

Comment: www.example.com/page-name1/uk  
I need this format url, so how to do this?

Comment: Well write a pattern that matches the format?

Comment: can you suggest like that format?

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself? Should not be that hard, to switch the order of the parts your current patterns had.